# Error 500 No Http response code found

Tags: php, curl, joomla, joomla2.5

joomla 2.5.18
php -5.4.12
apache - 2.4.4
mysql - 5.6.12 ,
I am trying to post data on particular url and get the response, Here is my code

```
jimport('joomla.http');
$data = array('foo' => 'bar'); //sample data array
$transport = null;
$transportWrappers=array('JHttpTransportCurl','JHttpTransportStream','JHttpTransportSocket');

$moduleParams = new JRegistry();
while (!$transport && $transportWrappers)
    try{
        $wrapper = array_shift($transportWrappers);
        $transport = new $wrapper($moduleParams);
    }
    catch (Exception $e){
        continue;
    }
$http = new JHttp($moduleParams, $transport);

$url = 'my_url';
$response = $http->post($url,$data);
print_r($response);
```

I have also checked other forums with same problem , they suggested to check #_update_sites table , my table is fine, no unknown data is there .
I am unable to figure out where is the problem.I tried the same code for different url.It worked.
I dont think there is problem in my url.
Here is my apache log error

> [Wed Mar 26 13:50:51.154818 2014] [:error] [pid 4504:tid 1664] [client
>   ::1:51174] PHP 13. JHttp->post()
>   C:\wamp\www\joomla\components\com_name\views\abc\tmpl\default.php:70
>   [Wed Mar 26 13:50:51.154818 2014] [:error] [pid 4504:tid 1664] [client
>   ::1:51174] PHP 14. JHttpTransportCurl->request()
>   C:\wamp\www\joomla\libraries\joomla\http\http.php:122 [Wed Mar
>   26 13:50:51.154818 2014] [:error] [pid 4504:tid 1664] [client
>   ::1:51174] PHP 15. JHttpTransportCurl->getResponse()
>   C:\wamp\www\joomla\libraries\joomla\http\transport\curl.php:134

Please help here.

[UPDATED]
It was the Wamp version problem , i tried the same codes in Xampp and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

**Introduction**

The Web server (running the Web Site) encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request by the client (e.g. your Web browser or our CheckUpDown robot) for access to the requested URL.

This is a 'catch-all' error generated by the Web server. Basically something has gone wrong, but the server can not be more specific about the error condition in its response to the client. In addition to the 500 error notified back to the client, the Web server should generate some kind of internal error log which gives more details of what went wrong. It is up to the operators of the Web server site to locate and analyse these logs. (Last updated: October 2013)

**Fixing 500 errors - general**

This error can only be resolved by fixes to the Web server software. It is not a client-side problem. It is up to the operators of the Web server site to locate and analyse the logs which should give further information about the error.

**Fixing 500 errors - CheckUpDown**

Our service monitors your site for HTTP errors like 500. Please contact us (email preferred) whenever you encounter 500 errors on your CheckUpDown account. We then have to liaise with your ISP and the vendor of the Web server software so they can trace the exact reason for the error. Correcting the error may require recoding program logic for the Web server software, which could take some time.

Comment: thanks for the reply , i will sure inform the server admins. Meanwhile, i am still trying to fix this problem , because  i run the same code 1 week ago and it was working and i was getting the response object. But its not working now .I tried everything.